# I can’t get the correct answer when work with cookies and few POST/GET req

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to parse the site - https://rentcar.gr/en/booking/cars
as I understood in the developer panel, I must first set up a post and then get a request to get the desired page, but I ran into a problem in my opinion with cookies

This is screen from developer panel of this requests(post -> get)

[image]
[image]
[image]

This my code firstly a get page for get token and take cookies, then use this data for POST req and save cookies, then use this cookies for get req but get wrong content looking at it, it seems to me that this is the code for the main page of the site

```
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://rentcar.gr/en/booking/cars"

work = Session()

req = work.get(api_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
token = soup.find('form').find('input').get('value')

data = {
    '_token': token,
    'pickUpLocation': '8',
    'pickUpDate': '22-02-2024',
    'pickUpTime': '10:00',
    'dropOffLocation': '6',
    'dropOffDate': '29-02-2024',
    'dropOffTime': '10:00',
    'driverAge': '25',
    'carID': '0',
    'minPickUpDate': '22-02-2024',
    'minDropOffDate': '22-02-2024',
}
req = work.post(api_url, cookies=req.cookies, data=data)
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(
    work.get(api_url, cookies=req.cookies).content, "html.parser"
)

for h3 in soup.select("h3.carname"):
    print(f'{h3.text:<60}')
```

Comment: You need to be aware that if the page is being rendered dynamically via javascript beautifulsoup will not help you.

Comment: how to check it and if its true how i can solve it

Comment: One way is to turn off javascript and see if you still get a coherent DOM

Answer (score 0):

second Api give you a response in HTML format.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(
    work.get(api_url, cookies=req.cookies).content, "html.parser"
)
for h3 in soup.find_all('h3'):
    print(h3.text)
```

[image]

Comment: this code does not work, it displays the main page and not the page with the car after entering all the data...

Comment: this text from your screen from main menu of web site, not of page with a lot of cars after post req

Comment: this is what you want brother, if you want to get h4 tag then find h4 and get text as same as h3